# Stretch background image to page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stretch the body background gradient to the whole page, independantly to how much content there is.

if I use the following css leads to a white page in case of longer content:
http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/1/

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

On the other hand unsetting the `html height` leads to a good result for large content:
http://jsfiddle.net/L6qM8/

But does not stretch the background for small content:
http://jsfiddle.net/6vaTX/1/

How would I get a linear gradient background independently from content?

*** EDIT: SUMMARY ***

1: http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/1/  --> scroll down and there won't be any background
2: http://jsfiddle.net/6vaTX/1/  --> background does not stretch to bottom
3: `background-size: cover;` does not help

Comment: What's wrong with keeping the height:100% on the html element?

Comment: Click here: http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/1/ and scroll down: there will be no background on bottom

Comment: @ProfHase85 I found out the solution: use `min-height:100%` instead of `height:100%` for `html` see [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of the background-size: cover and applying the css to the html instead of the body element and removing height 100% worked for me. I referenced this article: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/8/

```
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

hope it will help you

```
background-size:cover; //or 100%;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/4/)

Comment: IS the problem that it doesn't stretch out of the viewport?

Comment: your demo link is broken

Comment: this just make the background fixed, if you want it to stretch you have to use `min-height:100%` on `html`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
html
{
   min-height:100%;
}
```

the html element wasn't taking up the whole height of the iframe.

Comment: He clearly already has that in his code, in fact it is the very first thing in his code...

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/AE6dr/6/).

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(78, 75, 78) 42%, rgb(66, 45, 46) 71%, rgb(71, 51, 50) 86%);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```